# CSS div border shows up, but is transparent

Tags: css, border

I am trying to apply a border to only the left and right sides of a div with a solid color. When I look at the page, the elements within (which are set to fill the div width) shift over the proper number of pixels, but the border itself (a solid color) appears to not exist, or the border itself is transparent. How I get the solid color border to actually appear? Here is the CSS segment:

```
#menu {
border-left: 10px solid #490707;
border-right: 10px solid #490707;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) replicating the problem?

Comment: Sure thing: http://jsfiddle.net/rtqAq/

The banner image is not present, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: #490707 should be a dark red, so I'll assume it's of sufficient contrast to your background, and a 10 pixel thick solid line should be quite visible. Have you tried a tool such as FireBug to see all the CSS that's being applied to this menu div, in what order? Perhaps there's something changing the color, being applied _after_ #menu; or perhaps the menu ID isn't being applied at all (some other CSS is moving content around)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border isn't appearing because `#menu` height has "collapsed" due to having floated descendants (the list-items) .. you can establish a new block formatting context for `#menu`'s descendants by adding `overflow: hidden;` so that the floats are respected.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtqAq/1/

Eventually, when the [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/) is adopted by browsers, you'll be able to use the `contain-floats` value for the `min-height` and `min-width` properties so you don't have to use `overflow: hidden;` anymore.

1. [`contain-floats`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#the-contain-floats-value)

> Equivalent to ‘min-content’ except that when applied to the extent of a block box it forces the inner extent to be large enough to contain the margin boxes of any floats that originate inside the block and that participate in the same block formatting context as the block's immediate contents.

Comment: The border is now visible. Thank you!

Comment: You can clear the `#menu` using a a pseudo-element instead: http://jsfiddle.net/rtqAq/5/ - and that is one of the principal reasons for the new property I mentioned above.

Comment: Wait a minute... I added 'overflow: hidden;' to all of '#menu''s descendants and the hover menu is (still) broken.

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden;` as well, take a look at the fiddle I provided above.